# Added reference pictures are pink

Tags: image

I've added new images into a blender file and they turn up pink. I haven't moved the file, which I understand can affect how Blender finds them. I have tried packing and all sorts of things, but the image doesn't show up in the first place, unlike other questions I've seen where they came back a day later. I have tried both .jpg and .png files and nothing seems to work. I've tried **File** > **External Data** > **Report Missing Files** and nothing comes up as missing.

Answer (score 0):

These are the things to check -

- naming/paths - try to put the images in a path without gaps, or non-standard characters. First try something like C:\test.jpg, where nothing should go wrong.
- path of your blender file, same as above.
- image format - open the images in an image editor, resave them
- if these don't work, it might be some kind of a bug, specific to your operating system.